# slick grid frozenColumn blank when scoll the page

Tags: grid, slick

when i use slick grid frozenColumn function.
i move the bottom Scrollbar to the width as the frozencolumn width. 
then move the left Scrollbar down quickly. 
the frozenColumn become blank.

does the bug in slick grid. or need i do some setup

Comment: may not width as the frozencolumn, widht then the frozencolumn the the frozencolumn will blank always.

Comment: any body have the same issue? i think when we have much columns this issue will happen .as the slick grid demo less then 10 column will not have this issue. but when i crease the column to 200 it will come blank

Answer (score 0):

slick.grid.js

function appendRowHtml
code block

```
else if (( options.frozenColumn > -1 ) && ( i <= options.frozenColumn )) {
                    appendCellHtml(stringArrayL, row, i, colspan, d);
}
```

lost parameter d